# "Access is Denied" when using BreakRoleInheritence method on Drop Off Library in ItemUpdating event receiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an event receiver that is using the ItemUpdating event. I am trying to disinherit the item's permissions from parent and strip all permissions on the item upon being uploaded to the Drop Off Library. The reason for this is that the document contains sensitive information and should not be visible to anyone once it arrives in the Drop Off Library.

The code below is throwing the following error when executing the CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritence(true) line upon reaching the Drop Off Library: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

```
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(properties.ListItem.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.RootWeb)
                    {
                        SPListItem CurrentListItem = properties.ListItem;

                        SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments;

                        oSiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

                        oSiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            if (SPRoleAssColn[i].Member.Name != "System Account")
                            {
                                SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have also done the following things:
- made sure the Identity of the app pool is a site collection admin
- tried to get the list item again using GetItemById (but this throws an error that the item does not exist, since the item has still not been published yet - we need to remove permissions before the document is published - and we cannot force a check-in otherwise the drop off library might process and move the document to the its target library)
- tried getting the web and site options using guids
- tried many different combinations of placements with AllowUnsafeUpdates
- used the user token of a site collection admin to open the web objects

For some reason, the code above works fine when the document reaches the target library (as we are removing all the permissions AGAIN once the document arrives at the destination). This happens because the document is moved from the drop off library to the target library using the System Account.

Any thoughts on how to get around the "Access is Denied" error while utilizing a similar approach as above?

Answer (score 0):

And how this item is being sent to Drop off library? Via workflow, or when using OfficialFile.asmx? Can you check if this eventreceiver works properly when you manually upload file (most probably you will have to click 'submit' to force update, but maybe you can set fields in such way, that none of your Rules would match? I files get there via workflow, make sure that also account on which SPTimer4 service is running is site administrator on this site collection.

Also be careful, - i think there are two things that may not work as you expect in your event receiver:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (var oSiteCollection = new SPSite(properties.ListItem.Web.Url))
    {
        using (var oWebsite = oSiteCollection.RootWeb)
        {
             var currentListItem = properties.ListItem;
             oSiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
             oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

             currentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

             //You should take the RoleAssignments after breaking inheritance our you will be working on parents permissions. 
             var spRoleAssColn = currentListItem.RoleAssignments;

             oSiteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
             oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

             for (int i = spRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
             {
                 //I think it won't allow you to remove permissions for site administrator 
                 if (spRoleAssColn[i].Member.Name != "System Account" && !oWebsite.EnsureUser(spRoleAssColn[i].Member.LoginName).IsSiteAdmin)
                 {
                    spRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
});
```